# Can we see the UI view from Katalon with Kobiton for Mobile

Tags: katalon-studio

Is it possible to view the Mobile UI view, if we run our Mobile test scripts in Katalon with Kobiton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible from Katalon Studio. The automated session can be viewed directly from Kobiton page itself.